# Translucent status bar Android 4.4 has an offset

Tags: android

I am running this code on Android API level 19

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            final Window window = getWindow();
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
}
```

The status bar is translucent but it has a strange offset on the top. It works perfect on android 5.

Here is the code for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/statusbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/content_container" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: And here is the screenshot of the view]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, i've tried that and that doesn't work.

**Use this library:**
https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Here is the tutorial:

http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx

**Codes:**

```
SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
      tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
 tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
tintManager.setTintColor(Color.parseColor("#20000000"));
```

***Also you can try to find the height of the status bar with this method:***

```
// A method to find height of the status bar
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

**And i did this and it's working properly:**

> Create an **XML** file in your drawable folder(for exmaple: `kitkat_status_bar`) and put these codes on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/ColorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
   </layer-list>
```

Then you can use these codes for your `Activity`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            AppUtilsSetting.setTitleBarTint(this);
        }
```

**Here is the class:**

```
public static class AppUtilsSetting {

        public static void setTitleBarTint(Activity ac) {

            ac.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(ac);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintDrawable(ac.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.kitkat_status_bar));
        }
    }
```